# How to share instance between jest test files?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs, ts-jest

I want to share `testEnv` instance with different .ts files.

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    let testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
          projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID,
          firestore: {
            rules: fs.readFileSync("firestore.rules", "utf8"),
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: 8080
          },
        });
})
```

Basically my idea is inject `testEnv` to each file, But there is no way to inject instance to a "file", Any one got better idea to solve this?

I want to implement something like this:

```
import testFile1;
import testFile2;
import testFile3;

let testEnv
beforeAll(async () => {
  testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
      projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID,
      firestore: {
        rules: fs.readFileSync("firestore.rules", "utf8"),
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 8080
      },
    });
})

testFile1(testEnv);
testFile2(testEnv);
testFile3(testEnv);
```